# Using Pest.rs, is there a way to store comments as tokens?

Tags: parsing, rust, peg, pest

Pest.rs gives us a method of doing comments,

> `COMMENT` - runs between rules and sub-rules

But if we're building a linter we may want the comments. Is there a way to have them saved on the tree?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you'd use [`COMMENT`](https://pest.rs/book/grammars/syntax.html#implicit-whitespace) but not make it [silent](https://pest.rs/book/grammars/syntax.html#silent-and-atomic-rules). Haven't actually tried it so not an answer.

Comment: @mcarton I never even thought that at... Good thinking my man, make it an answer. That was easy as hell. I read the docs 3 times and never thought syntax. No one better to write a parser, amirite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd use [`COMMENT`](https://pest.rs/book/grammars/syntax.html#implicit-whitespace) but not make it [silent](https://pest.rs/book/grammars/syntax.html#silent-and-atomic-rules).

For example this will handle C-like comments but they won't appear in the output (what most people want most of the time):

```
COMMENT = _{ "/*" ~ (!"*/" ~ ANY)* ~ "*/" }
```

While this will make them present in the output:

```
COMMENT = { "/*" ~ (!"*/" ~ ANY)* ~ "*/" }
```